# Delete a file that "does not exist" with a strange name

Tags: cmd.exe, file-management, special-characters

I've read about deleting files which "do not exist"

and got as far as `del /q /s filename` in command prompt.

However, the file is named `COM^sv3.O[e` in the browser.

but when i type in dir it = [image]

Of which there are charaters I cant even type.
Even copying from teh command prompt, as is. It still "cannot find" the file.

Any ideas on how to delete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That backspace character can be a problem. Use the [UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Naming_Convention#Uniform_Naming_Convention) path. Switch to the directory where the file is stored, then use this command:

```
del \\?\%cd%\COM^sv?3.0[e
```

Of course this is assuming that the filename shown in your screenshot is complete. If not, then just reduce it to `del \\?\%cd%\COM*`

Also, did you try simply deleting the file in Explorer?

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar issue and had to remove a directory called `abc ` (trailing space). You cand do that with 
`rmdir "\\?\c:\Users\YourUserName\Desktop\abc "`

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to see all files and directories starting with "COM":

> dir /a COM*

If there is only the problematic file, try to delete it using:

> del COM*

Comment: If i type del COM* it lists the file, then "cannot find" it `K:\myfolder>del COM*`
`K:\myfolder\COM^sv⌂3.O[e`
`The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Have you checked for filesystem errors?
do a checkdsk /f c:

Comment: Could that be a link ?

Comment: You could try getting the short file name (8.3 characters, something like COMSV3~1) of the file with `dir /x COM*`, then `del (short name)`

Comment: This seems to be behaviour related to DOS COM ports. The files I had issues with were created by winrar to preview.